# In Virtuemart 2.0 How to create invoice only if the Paypal payment is success

Tags: php, paypal, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I using Joomla 2.5.6 and Virtuemart 2.0. In the order section presently the invoice is created always with the payment method Paypal. I need to change invoice creation in Paypal payment method, Only if the payment is success.

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the appropriate order status for **successful transaction** and **capture payment** under:

```
Virtuemart -> Shop -> Payment Methods -> *Paypal -> Configuration -> Successful transactions / Capture Payment
```

> **SUCCESSFUL TRANSACTIONS**
>
> *By default, Successful transactions are set to Confirmed.*
>
> The order is set to this status when PayPal informs that transaction
>   was successful and the money is in the merchant's account.
>
> **CAPTURE PAYMENT**
>
> *By default, Capture Payment are set to Shipped.*
>
> This parameter is only valid, if the Payment action parameter is set
>   to Authorization and Capture
>
> If the payment is captured via the PayPal account, the order will be
>   set to this status in VirtueMart
>
> VirtueMart will capture the payment
>   of the  previously created authorization, when the order is set to
>   this status.

If you want to create a new order status only for paypal payments you could do it under:

```
Virtuemart -> Configuration -> Order Statuses
```

Invoice creation handled at:

```
Virtuemart -> Configuration -> Configuration -> Checkout -> Default Order Status to create an invoice
```

Reference: [Virtuemart Paypal](http://docs.virtuemart.net/manual/shop-menu/payment-methods/paypal.html)